# ASP.NET Core API using JwtAuth, Non-MS browsers do not allow for smart cards

Tags: google-chrome, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API backend. This project runs on IIS. We have some decorators at the top of each controller that require the user to authenticate.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBvfc.jpg)

Now in our client app, we get a dialog in Edge that allows for a smart card or a username/password combo.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFgrP.jpg)

This all works fine, however in a non-MS browser, all we get is a simple username and password dialog:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xofML.jpg)

We want the same functionality in all browsers. Please help me understand what we need to do in order to make this work.

We have tried multiple browsers and the full experience only works in Edge

Comment: I suggest you could check it by follow this [article](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7014689?hl=en).